# Ender 3 inconsistent Z homing

Tags: creality-ender-3, homing

I have an Ender 3 with an MKS GEN L V2.0 with Marlin firmware and a BLTouch.

When I first turn it on, it homes all axes correctly but after the first print it thinks the z axis is off anywhere from .02 to .06 mm when really it still homes to 10 mm.

What would be causing this? As you can see in the picture it thinks it's at 9.94 mm when it's really at 10 mm after homing.

[image: Photo of display panel showing incorrect Z setting]

Comment: Is this the position directly after leveling, i.e. the state of the machine after `G29`; I read you say `after the first print`, do you mean a completed print or the leveling of the first print? What does the state of this display express? Is this after printing an object of 10 mm high?

Answer (score 0):

The height after leveling is determined by the firmware configuration.

```
#define Z_AFTER_HOMING  10      // (mm) Height to move to after homing Z
```

After `G29` the display of my machine doesn't show 10 mm either, it shows 11.8 mm instead:

[image]

The difference is exactly the Z-probe offset (trigger point to nozzle distance + paper thickness).

[image]